# 32 bit application not working on 64 bit windows 7

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit, x86-64

I made a software on visual studio 2010, my system is windows 7 32 bit. In my system , my software is working great but when I install this software in windows 7 64 bit OS, installation is fine. But when double click to open it, it stops working. So,I view details, these are files which describe the problem:-

```
 C:\Users\hesh\AppData\Local\Temp\WERCADC.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
  C:\Users\hesh\AppData\Local\Temp\WERE56F.tmp.appcompat.txt
  C:\Users\hesh\AppData\Local\Temp\WERE58F.tmp.mdmp
```

Can any one tell me how to get rid of this issue.
Here is the screen shot of the problem:-
[image]

Comment: Not these files that causes errors, but the contents of these files help diagnose the errors. Read the contents.

Comment: The easiest approach to this problem is to install Visual Studio on a 64-bit machine, and run the program in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure wether this is really 64 bit problem. But still you cantry to run it in a compability mode s. 
[run-a-program-in-compatibility-mode-in-windows-8](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-8/run-a-program-in-compatibility-mode-in-windows-8/)

The files you posted are some kind of logfiles indicated where the problem lies. So the best way would be to read the files.

Also you can try to remove some startup code to isolate the code which causes the problem. And you could also post some code here perhaps we can see a potential problematic thing.

Are you using PInvokes?